# JavaDocs for Tibco datagrams (TibrvMsg)?

Tags: java, api, messaging, tibco, dataformat

Does anyone know of available Javadoc for Tibco rvd datagrams (specifically, class "com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvMsg")? It is not hard to decompile classes to get signatures, but that does not tell a lot about expected optimal usage and such.

All I need is simple read/write functionality for interoperability purposes, but ideally using recommended methods, and sometimes things like that are included in javadocs (I know that the product is not actively developed or supported, but there are lots of legacy systems that use it; and some non-rvd systems that use the data format itself for convenience (?)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All TIBCO documentation including for Rendezvous may be found here:

http://power.tibco.com/pubslib/

Though you may need a customer id or support contract to access it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can find a customer id, we are a customer so it should be possible to figure that out.

Comment: Indeed. And if you have Rendezvous installed on your machine, the documentation (including javadoc) should be available too (on Windows go to Start > All Programs > Tibco > [Product] > Documentation).

Answer (score 3):

If you installed RV you can go here:
/DOC/HTML/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm

but don't use Google Chrome to view it - only Firefox and Internet Explorer will work